# Should I implement functions inside the class to adapt MVC?

Tags: swift, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm new to design patterns. I have a class called `CustomClass` which is a subclass of `UILabel`, I'm using **Swift**, within the app I'd perform several operations to instances of this class, such as rotating, resizing and etc..

Now it's the question, I can either implement these functions within the class or their parent `ViewController`, which is the right way in order to adapt the app to the **MVC**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single "right" way. As usual with these things, it depends.

If your operations contain UI-specific code, and especially if you want to reuse your CustomClass just like a UILabel, you would probably do better to put the operations into CustomClass.

In general it is better that UI specifics are in the view and not in the Controller. The Controller tells the View what to do in an abstract way. The View might reveal methods `rotate`, `resize` etc. which the Controller would use.

In your case, you are developing a UI component, so the distinction is not so clear-cut. The Controller logic might be quite complicated and to extract it from the widget itself would be useful for testing and reuse. You might consider using `Look` and `Feel` instead of `View` and `Controller` as suggested in [this article](http://blog.davidpeterson.co.uk/2012/07/look-and-feel.html).